# .ajax load remote page content to javascript var

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to get a short string hosted on a server where I do not have access to the data as XML, JSON, etc. I am trying to use either .load or .ajax to do this. I want to be able to parse the data into a javascipt array. The entire contents of the remote page is text and I am happy to take all of it and remove what I do not need via a small javascript. I have tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"http://url:8888/data", success:function(result){
    $("div").html(result);
  }});
});});
</script>
```

I have two questions. 
1- why does this not work? 
2- What would be the best way to store the string in a javascript var?

I am sure JQuery is working correctly.

Comment: you DO know that browsers do not allow any ajax calls to any domain different than the domain of the original HTML? So your page also loads from http://url:8888, right?

Comment: I did NOT know that (newbie, I am coming over to the web stuff from a Java app background) Would you mind letting me know how I should go about getting the contents of the remote site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be to long to post here (really). But look those up:

- Same Origin Policy
- Padded JSON

If you have no control over the remote site, you have lost - you will not get any data from it by Ajax (which is actually a feature, not a limitation of the technology). One way of circumventing the protection would be to build a proxy that just mirrors the remote service you need to reach and makes it available in the same domain that your main HTML came from.

Comment: I was able to get the data from the remote site using PHP CURL as a data bridge. Thanks